# argon one case script for fan/power switch not working on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, raspberrypi, fan, 20.10

i am trying to install the software for the argon one case for controlling fan and power switch.
the makers software does not work on ubuntu, i found script that is supposed to resolve [this is the location of said script](https://github.com/meuter/argon-one-case-ubuntu-20.04.git)
 this problem but i get the following fault **chmod: missing operand after ‘755’** the line generating this fault is **sudo chmod 755 $configscript** .i am totally new to linux and have very limited knowledge of programming in general.if anyone could point me in the right direction to resolving this problem it would be greatly appreciated.i would like to get the case fan and power switch working but for me the most important thing would be understanding the reason for the fault as i am trying to learn linux and so far have managed to understand and solve the problems i have come up against with a little online research but with this i don't see the problem
system details
raspberry pi 4 8gb
ubuntu 20.10 groovy gorilla
argon one case

many thanks for taking the time to read my question

Comment: Sounds like the variable `$configscript` is not set. If you can share the source code of the script, we might be able to locate the problem and a possible solution.

Comment: happy to do so but its 690 lines or can post the github address of the code which ever you suggest or any better ways

Comment: Please edit your post to include github link then.

Comment: It's very odd - I just looked through the script and the command seems ok to me. Would you mind trying running it again, and edit your post with the exact commands you type in, and output also?

Comment: i just tried again with the same result ,chmod: missing operand after ‘755’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information. what i entered was as seen in the script i just cut and pasted into terminal

Comment: Try and comment out line 533 (put a `#` as first character) and run script again. Also, please inspect line 55, and check that it actually reads: `configscript=/usr/bin/argonone-config` (especially that what's in front of the = is spelled right).

Comment: new fault message                                                                                                    rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
chmod: missing operand after ‘666’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.line 55 looks good

Comment: Please join this chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/116733/cctin01?tab=general

Comment: i tried but dont have enough reputation points to talk

Comment: Ok. Does the script reach this step? "Step 8 (extra) - generating $tempmonscript"

Comment: oh and stick an echo before 553 to print the content of $configscript

Comment: yes it reaches step 8

Comment: Try chat again now

Comment: i can see your messages but cant talk

Comment: ok just stuck edit on 553 dont get any error messages and script appears to run to end, i'll reboot and the try to configue

Comment: Interesting to see if this works - I have absolutely no clue why you get the errors, script looks fine. Hope it works for you, 'cos it's a cool case! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands manually:

```
sudo echo 'while true; do clear; date; echo "$(( $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) / 1000 ))°C"; sleep 1 ; done' > /usr/bin/argonone-tempmon

sudo chmod 775 /usr/bin/argonone-config

sudo chmod 775 /usr/bin/argonone-tempmon
```

See if it works now by typing either `argonone-config` or `argonone-tempmon`.

Comment: still not working ,but very much appreciate your efforts.obrigado and thanks

Comment: :-( Very strange.

Comment: yeah ,just when i thought i was beginning to get to grips with terminal i get knocked back .but i know i have a lot to learn .no doubt it wont be the last time . thanks very much for trying it is very much appreciated . its been 40+ years since i last got involved in programming so its not a surprise to me that its going to be a steep learning curve

Comment: I might give it a try to create the proper script files myself tomorrow, if I have the time. Later! :-)

Comment: well dont put yourself out its nnnot a big issue for me the fan and power button                                          both work just not able to adjust settings, fan is my real issue want to set to always on really as i live on a boat in the tropics so heat is an issue and noise isnt